# Independent vs Overall Percentage of Turns in Game where Next Player is Probabilistically Determined.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling, programming

I'm writing a program in which there are *n* "players". On each player's turn, the next player is randomly determined with a weight. My goal is to have each player have it be their turn a certain percentage of the time (e.g. Player 1 gets 0.20 of all turns).

If there were three players, [1, 2, 3] and I would like each of them to have it be their turn [0.20, 0.50, 0.30] of the total number of turns respectively. When I run this simulation several thousand times and count up the number of turns each player takes, however, I get a distribution of [0.258, 0.403, 0.339] of the turns for each player.

I am picking the next player by repeatedly sampling the list of players until I get one that is not the current player.

I think this is being complicated by the fact that the next player must not be the player whose turn it currently is, but I am unsure why this. How can I sample the next player and achieve some specific proportion of turns in the long run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player $2$ will get $\frac {0.5}{0.5+0.3}=\frac 58$ of the turns after player $1$ and $\frac 57$ of the turns after player $3$.  If player $1$ gets $a$ of the turns, player $2$ gets $b$ of the turns, and player $3$ gets $c$ of the turns, we can solve the equations for the steady state
$$a=\frac 25b+\frac 27c\\
b=\frac 58a+\frac 57c\\
c=\frac 38a+\frac 35b\\
a+b+c=1$$
Which gives $a=\frac {16}{62}\approx 0.258,b=\frac{25}{62}\approx 0.403,c=\frac{21}{62}\approx 0.339$.  Your simulation works quite well.

With your constants, the simple thing is to realize that if player $2$ is going to get half the turns and cannot have two in a row, he must get every other turn.  Let player $2$ go after both $1$ and $3$, then after player $2$ pick the next to play with $0.4$ for player $1$ and $0.6$ for player $2$.

Comment: This was what I thought, but then there is no randomness for player 2.

Comment: As I said, you can't have randomness if you want a player to take half the turns and not have two in a row.

Comment: Note that it is not "strictly half" (whatever it means), but only asymptotically.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! I wasn't thinking of it in terms of paths that lead to each turn.
If I want to find the inputs that result in these totals, do I now balance for a, b, c  = 0.2, 0.5, 0.3?
Also, do you happen to know where I could learn more about this type of situation?

Comment: It is a Markov chain, which I have not studied.  You are specifying the transition probabilities and are looking for the long term average of the time spent in each state.  Those terms should let you find some literature.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't change your picking algorithm, then I only have a partial solution for the case $n = 3$.

Let's say you want a distribution of $[u, v, w]$ with $u + v + w = 1$ and $u, v, w < 0.5$.

Then you should defined the weights $[a, b, c]$ as follows. First calculate $p = \frac 1 {1 - 2u}$, $q = \frac 1 {1 - 2v}$, $r = \frac 1 {1 - 2w}$, then define $$a = \frac p{p + q + r}, b = \frac q{p + q + r}, c = \frac r{p + q + r}.$$

Now you may use your algorithm with the new weights $[a, b, c]$ to pick the players, and the resulting distribution will be exactly $[u, v, w]$.

---

Currently I don't know if this method can be extended to more than $3$ players.